# URL Rewrite Rules for domain and subdirectory

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

We're trying to rewrite to a specific domain and subdirectory, when we rewrite to the domain it works fine but trying to get to the subdirectory either brings up the wrong page or doesn't work at all.

Here is what we have now that is working to rewrite the domain, but doesn't go to the proper subdirectory and page.

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
      <rewrite>
        <rules>
          <rule name="Rewrite to site.firstdomain.com">
            <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="https://site.firstdomain.com/{R:1}" />
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

With the above set up entering https://site.seconddomain.com takes us to https://site.seconddomain.com/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2f
But we really want to go to
https://site.seconddomain.com/Account/Login?co=7xTixDp4F%2fzAp0WobaTTjw%3d%3d

But if I try

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
      <rewrite>
        <rules>
          <rule name="Rewrite to site.firstdomain.com">
            <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="https://site.firstdomain.com/Account/Login?co=7xTixDp4F%2fzAp0WobaTTjw%3d%3d" />
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

We still don't get taken to the https://site.seconddomain.com/Account/Login?co=7xTixDp4F%2FzAp0WobaTTjw%3D%3D address and the page displays the wrong images and then eventually Chrome says there is a memory error.

Is this something to do with the special characters in co=7xTixDp4F%2FzAp0WobaTTjw%3D%3D ?

Or I'm beginning to think this isn't a URL rewrite issue and is something with the page/system, any ideas?

Comment: Some special characters in the URL cannot be used directly, you need to escape or encode them before they can be rewritten, but after my test, I found a strange problem 
 `ReturnUrl=%2f ` and `co=7xTixDp4F%2fzAp0WobaTTjw%3d%3d` are not the same after encoding, how did you get the them? please post more information about it.

Comment: ReturnUrl=%2f is what is automatically being returned by the site when going to site.firstdomain.com or site.seconddomain.com using the first rewrite rule.

Comment: I suggest you to use failed request tracing to see detailed request information, because if your request url is `site.firstdomain.com` or `site.seconddomain.com`, {R:1} is null and there will be no other strings.